# green threads and celery

Tags: python, multithreading, celery

I am a newbie to the concept of green threads.
I have a system using Celery to dispatch some tens of workers at a time

These threads sometime worker hard CPU wise, crunching numbers, and sometimes wait on url requests.

Is there a way to have celery spawn "green threads" to make better use of CPU for example?
Or do I have to incorporate the "green" threading into my worker code somehow?

Comment: Using green threads wouldn't make better use of CPU, especially not when the workers can be performing CPU-intensive tasks. Regular threads waiting for I/O don't consume a whole lot of CPU anyway.

Comment: Celery supports using eventlet or gevent, so you can route I/O-bound tasks to eventlet/gevent workers.  See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html and http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html